# Is it possible to filter dbpedia results using url parameters?

Tags: dbpedia

A sample dbpedia page: http://dbpedia.org/page/United_States

How do get back just the abstract text?

Can this be done using just url parameters and get the result back in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result back in JSON is easy, try this http://dbpedia.org/data/United_States.jsod

for more control I suppose you need to use [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/2009/Talks/0615-qbe/)